# AWS API Gateway key issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I am trying to use aws API Gateway with authentication. I created an API key and set requirement to true in Method Request. But when I'm sending the request with specified "x-api-key" in header, I still get

```
 {
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
```

Is there anything more that I need to configure or something, for fixing this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm that a method and resource exist for your route of your request

Comment: yes, route is connected to lambda function, and requirement for api key in request is set to true, when I set it to false everyting works correctly

Comment: Have you added a usage plan and attached this to your API stage?

Comment: Can you show how exactly do you call your api with the header? Do you test it with `curl` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst creating the API key is part of the solution you will also need to create a [usage plan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) and attach your API key to it.

Once this has been completed you'll want to associate it with the API stage(s) that your API key should work with.

[This guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-usage-plans.html) should provide additional information for creating this

Comment: So you created and assigned to your stage? And then attached API key to your usage plan?

Comment: yes, I have created a usage plan,attached to a stage, added an existing key to it

Comment: Hmm, peculiar. Try creating a new deployment and deploy to the stage?